# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect, dispatch

I'm trying to get the list of user and clients using dipatch and I get this error:
"Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions."

Here is the code where I get the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(ListClients());
        dispatch(ListUsers());
    }, [dispatch]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the definition of ListClients() and ListUsers ?

I'm pretty sure your code should look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ListClients);
    dispatch(ListUsers);
}, [dispatch]);
```

Or your functions do not have the right signature.

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't import the methods from the right path! Thanks for mentioning to check the definition of the functions!